# Alarm Manager to push notification at a specific time daily except Sunday and disable push to show upon triggered

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

When it is the first time user logs into the app, i use Alarm Manager and Pending Intent to enable push notification everyday 1 hour before a specific cut-off time.

However, I want it to push daily except Sunday of the week. How can I do it? (Note that i tried setrepeating but it does not work for the new version I have which is API 26)

Also, it will push notification everytime i login. How can i prevent it from showing during login (trigger the next day)?

I have a method called scheduleNotification in my first CatalogueFragment upon login which contains the following:

```
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("notif_content", content);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("isEnglish", isEnglish);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("notif_id", notificationId);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("hour", "" + (Integer.parseInt(hour) - 1));
    notificationIntent.putExtra("mins", mins);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, notificationId, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    loginPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    loginPrefsEditor = loginPreferences.edit();
    if (loginPreferences.getBoolean("FirstTimeLogin", true)) {
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        loginPrefsEditor.putBoolean("FirstTimeLogin", false);
        loginPrefsEditor.apply();
    }
```

In my AlarmReceiver.class

```
 public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String isEnglish = intent.getStringExtra("isEnglish");
    final String id = "my_channel_id_01";
    CharSequence name = "channel_name";
    String description = "channel_description";
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
    int notificationId = intent.getIntExtra("notif_id", 0);
    String hour = intent.getStringExtra("hour");
    String mins = intent.getStringExtra("mins");
    String cutoffHour = "" + (Integer.parseInt(hour) + 1);
    String cutofftime = cutoffHour + ":" + mins;

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(hour));
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(mins));

    String content = "Please place order before " + cutofftime + " AM for today's delivery";

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("notif_id", Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("ddHHmmss").format(new Date())));
        notificationIntent.putExtra("hour", hour);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("mins", mins);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("isEnglish", isEnglish);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("notif_content", content);

        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance);
        mChannel.setDescription(description);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, id)
                .setContentTitle("Gentle reminder")
                .setContentText(content)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        Intent notifIntent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
        PendingIntent activity = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, notificationId, notifIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(activity);
        Notification notification = builder.build();
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, notificationId, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Your problem is not clear. Please explain exactly what is happening or nor happening.

Comment: Notification push daily. i want it push daily except sunday

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger an alarm daily except Sunday, you can do that one of 2 ways:
- Set the alarm to trigger for the next day. When the alarm goes off, check if the next day is a Sunday. If it is a Sunday, set the alarm to trigger in 2 days (on Monday), otherwise set the alarm to trigger the next day
- Set a repeating alarm that triggers every day. When the alarm goes off, check if it is Sunday and if so, just ignore the alarm.

Comment: how to ignore the alarm?

Comment: You ignore the alarm by doing nothing when `onReceive()` is called.